# clang compiled program throws std::bad_any_cast during std::any_cast

Tags: c++, gcc, casting, clang, c++17

I'm working on an application where I use `std::any`.

Recently I've discovered that when I compile it with clang I'm getting `bad_any_cast` exception on one of the `std::any_cast`s.

I'm sure I'm casting to right type. I've added some dumps of `typeid(T).name()` to `cout` to be sure there is no difference between type inserted into `std::any` and type i'm trying to cast to.

I was trying to write simple program to demonstrate it but I cannot reproduce it.

What's worth mentioning: 
I'm passing a pack of `std::any` (each contains different type inside) and only one has problems (its a `std::map<ENUM, int>`).

Problem disappears when I switch to `boost::any` (or if I build my app with gcc).

I've dived into `std::any_cast` implementation and it fails on:

```
  template<typename _Tp>
    void* __any_caster(const any* __any)
    {
      if constexpr (is_copy_constructible_v<decay_t<_Tp>>)
      {
          if (__any->_M_manager == &any::_Manager<decay_t<_Tp>>::_S_manage)
          {
              any::_Arg __arg;
               __any->_M_manager(any::_Op_access, __any, &__arg);
              return __arg._M_obj;
          }
        }
      return nullptr;
    }
```

Second if statement with `(__any->_M_manager == &any::_Manager<decay_t<_Tp>>::_S_manage)` doesn't pass.

It seems to me like there are a few instances of `any::_Manager<decay_t<_Tp>>::_S_manage` for the same `_Tp` (possibly caused by my application consisting of a few modules) but I cannot reproduce it on a simpler example.

Do you guys have any suggestions or hints how can I deal with it?

**EDIT**

Inspired by comments and answers, I've created example where I mess up with default visibility (which is also something I do in my app) and that seems to be the root of the problem.

Files:

**lib.cpp**

```
#include <any>
#include <map>

enum class D
{
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
};

int read(const std::any& a)
{
    auto map = std::any_cast<std::map<D, int>>(a);
    return map.begin()->second;
}

std::any create()
{
    std::map<D, int> b = { {D::c, 5} };

    std::any a(b);

    return a;
}
```

**lib2.cpp**

```
#include <any>
#include <map>

std::any create();
int read(const std::any& a);

__attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) std::any build_bar2()
{
    return create();
}

__attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) int read_foo2(const std::any& a)
{
    return read(a);
}
```

**lib3.cpp**

```
#include <any>
#include <map>

int read(const std::any &);
std::any create();

__attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) int read_foo3(const std::any& a)
{
    return read(a);
}

__attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) std::any build_bar3()
{
    return create();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <any>

int read_foo2(const std::any& a);
std::any build_bar2();

int read_foo3(const std::any& a);
std::any build_bar3();


int main()
{
    const std::any& a = build_bar3();
    int av = read_foo2(a);

    const std::any& b = build_bar2();
    int bv = read_foo3(a);

    return av == bv? 1: 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CPP=clang++

all: main

lib.o: lib.cpp
    $(CPP) -std=c++17 -fvisibility=hidden -g -O0 -fPIC -c lib.cpp -o lib.o

lib2.so: lib2.cpp lib.o
    $(CPP) -std=c++17 -fvisibility=hidden -g -O0 -fPIC -shared lib2.cpp lib.o -o lib2.so

lib3.so: lib3.cpp lib.o
    $(CPP) -std=c++17 -fvisibility=hidden -g -O0 -fPIC -shared lib3.cpp lib.o -o lib3.so


main: main.cpp lib3.so lib2.so
    $(CPP) -std=c++17 -fvisibility=hidden -g -O0 main.cpp ./lib2.so ./lib3.so -o main

clean:
    rm -f ./lib.o ./lib2.so ./lib3.so ./main
```

So I have 2 shared libraries which are linking common static lib responsible for `std::any` creation and casting. When `std::any` is created in one instation of static lib and casted in another I get an exception.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your code demonstrating this exception

Comment: @Barry the whole deal is that I cannot reproduce it. I was hoping for someone having the same issue (caused by compiler bug?) or suggestion what can go wrong with `std::any` with given implementation so I can generate smaller example and fill a bug (if it really is a bug, not a platform/ABI/linker/whatever limitation). I was trying to build a shared library constructing `std::any` and then passing it to another library where it is casted (as that's the root of the problem IMHO) but it all works fine.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak you can reproduce it in your full code. Can't you cut down your code by removing code bit by bit. Sure this takes quite a bit of time, but otherwise this question is just based around a lot of speculation.

Comment: The OP @Michal has reported this bug upstream to llvm:

https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38485

Comment: I just tested again with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62) on macOS 10.15.7, and I'm not able to reproduce the problem. So, I guess it has been fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on a Unix like Linux or OS X, the C++ type ID is handled by a pointer to type information, not a name string match.

That means that if you have shared libraries or static libraries that have the "same" type, but they have their own individual copies of it, the type info will not match up.

This may or may not be your situation.

I believe you'll have to define your types used in your `any` in a common shared library, declared with default visibility. That should make all of your other shared libraries use that copy instead of a hidden copy from their static library.

Comment: If two libraries define the same type (by name) and you're trying to cast to one of these shared types, won't the result be a linker error of sorts?

Comment: @rubenvb it could conceivably be two non-exported types with the same name (potentially from the same header), wrapped in an any type when passing library boundaries. But speculating on this is really not all that useful, this question would really benefit from a reproduction example.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak I added a possible solution.

Comment: @ZanLynx thx for your answer Zan, but my case is a little bit more complicated I guess - instead of a common static library like in my simple example, I have a template used in a few shared libraries. What's interesting, only the enum seems to be problematic type. Other (complex) types are working (when placed into `std::any`). Anyway I'll need to figure out some nice mechanism to protect me against such problems in the future.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Each library creates its own definition of the template type. So the libraries only recognize their own type when put into an `any` object, because they use their own pointers to typeinfo.

Comment: @ZanLynx I wonder what libstdc++'s std::any and boost::any do differently than libc++'s std::any? Because the reproduction example works with gcc's std::any and boost::any, but not clang's std::any.